# Handle Activities programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a class MyApp extends Application that should handle activities.
After starting the activity with:

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ControlActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

How to close it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, sorry. You don't get an Activity object from `startActivity()`. The best you can is open another activity with a flag that clears the running activities.